# Can't assign template to a menu item Joomla

Tags: templates, joomla2.5, menuitem

I have default template for all pages on my website, and 1 different template only for 1 menu item.

So, It worked very well, 1 page had special Landing page Template and other pages worked with another template.
However, today I discovered that Landing page shows with another template for other pages... But I didn't do anything to templates or menus, so I'm surprised that it stoped working.

I decided to assign landing page template to that menu item again, but even if the template assigned to the menu item, it still shows with another template. So I tried to assign standard joomla template to page and it didn't work...

Seems, Like joomla doesn't pay attantion to whatever I assign, it show everything with 1 template which I had on all pages except Landing page.

But, when I click "Preview" of the Landing page template in template manager it shows the template well, so everything is ok with the tempalte.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please try to assign your default template to all pages, and the second template from: `Extensions -> Template Manager -> *Your Template -> Menus assignment`

Comment: Itried it, but it doesn't work. As I said, seems like joomla just ignorign everything I assign.

Comment: Please try to clear your browser cache, joomla cache and mysql session table.

Comment: I cleaned Browser Cache, sessions table and tried on a different computer, but still the same. Problem must somewhere in settings or etc... I'm pretty good in Joomla, I tried a lot of things but no go. It is really strange

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, which worked for me... http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2662700

The problem caused by SEF, but I'm not sure why would I have such problem... because I didn't change anything and it worked well the day before.... However, this thing worked

```
// Get the id of the active menu item
  $menu = $this->getMenu();
  $item = $menu->getActive();
  if (!$item) {
     //added here TO FIX THE ISSUE
     $this->route();
     //END CODE CHANGED      

     $item = $menu->getItem(JRequest::getInt('Itemid'));
  }
```

Comment: If someone knows why such problem could appear, please tell me.